# When two things are so related it is situationally useful to think of them as one thing

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

My line of work is abstract - I could name some items, but it would not help.

So, I have two nouns.  They have a parent-child relationship. But lately I realize that it is sometimes unhelpful to treat these items as though they are separate. That is, the child's allowable **behaviors** are tightly controlled by the parent's.

'associated' and 'coupled' are too weak

'parasitic' has a negative connotation

'master/slave' ehhh no.

'major/minor' maybe but doesn't really imply behavior, and this is all about behavior.

And I need a word that describes the child item, and a word for the parent too.  I could call the child node 'dependent' but then the parent node would be called ???

Comment: Everything depends on what metaphor you're using. Since you gave no examples, we can't tell anything about the nature of the relation without some better description than "parent/child". And whatever you finally decide on, bear in mind that you don't get to define what it means; only your readers do. (I'm assuming you're writing rather than talking about this, And if you have nodes and connections, what's wrong with graph theory?

Comment: Maybe you could say that the child's behaviors are **inherited** from the parent?

Answer (score 1):

An example of this relationship occurs in the **Observer Design Pattern**.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

The names for the parent and child here would be **subject** and **observer**.

A different example, which puts more emphasis on the parent’s ability to control as opposed to the child’s ability to interpret, can be found in **Control Theory**.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory

Here the parent would be the **controller**. The child could be descibed generically as a **dependent**.

These are examples from the world of machines. The human world offers many more examples, such as master/servant, parent/child, captain/mate, etc. However, if the intent is to *not* anthropomorphize the description, electrical and computer engineering offers some possibilities.

In the first example, you have an **observing** relationship. In the second case, you have a **controlling** relationship.